# Align item vertically with flex

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a woocommerce store and all of my product images are with flexbox and align items in mid. I install a plugin which changes the picture on hover, in this class, the align don't work, it stretches my picture. But the main picture is not stretch

I made
    display: flex
    height: 320px
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center

You can see all here: http://fistukids.de/shop/

Just hover on a picture, then you can see it aligns on top

Answer (score 0):

I think you want it vertically.

With flexbox you do it with:

```
flex-direction: row/column
```

In your case it would be column.
Hope I understood you right.

Comment: yes, i want it to align vertically like the main picture. but also flex-direction doesnt work for me on the second image class. do you testet it in the inspector?

Comment: Sry my internet is slow, so i can't help you much. When I get home, I take a better look.

I just made this answer, because this is how you align it vertically.

Comment: cool. thanks bro. i have 320px height viewport and the first image already works with justify-content. only the second image on hover has this problem. would be nice if you check it later